# In Microsoft Word 2011, Shift seems to be acting as a Command - how do I make it stop?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

Some specific behaviors I'm observing in Microsoft Word 2011 on my Mac:

- Shift + F moves the cursor into the Find box on the toolbar, instead of typing a "F" character.
- Shift + 9 opens help instead of typing a "(".

It seems like the Shift key is functioning as a Command key. I haven't made any changes to my Word settings to customize keyboard shortcuts. I did install another IME last night and configure the shortcuts to switch between IMEs, but the behavior only occurs in MS Word.

Any ideas on restoring default functionality?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you could try resetting the default shortcuts from the settings...

This is an excerpt from a Microsoft support article on the Office shortcut settings...

> **Reset all keyboard shortcuts**
>
> On the Tools menu, click Customize Keyboard.
>
> To restore keyboard shortcuts to their original state, click Reset All, and then in the confirmation message, click Yes.
>
> NOTE   Keyboard shortcuts for tasks are reset.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-keyboard-shortcut-1796e9a2-3748-4cf0-b163-24a65479caa6)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried your suggestion, but the "Reset All" button was greyed out, indicating, I suppose, that all the shortcuts were already in the original state. Certainly, when I went to look at the "EditFind" option, [Command]+F was listed as a shortcut but [Shift]+F was not, even though both of those move focus to the Find box when the cursor is in the main document.